# Pulling values from complex lists in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to pull the values out of a complicated list structure.

Given something like this:

```
[{:a "whatever" :b [:c "foo"]} :e {:f "boo"} :g {:h [:i 62281]}]
```

I'd like to get:

```
["whatever" "foo" "boo" 62281]
```

So far I've only gotten to this point:

```
((62281) nil (boo) nil whatever foo)
```

Here's the code:

```
(defn get-values [params]
  (apply conj
         (map (fn [part]
                (if (not (keyword? part))
                    (map (fn [v]
                           (if (vector? v)
                               (last v)
                               v))
                         (vals part))))
              params)))
```

1. I can't seem to get rid of the nil's
2. I can't figure out why the values after a certain point are in lists.
3. I figure there's got to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix the data structure and everything will fall in place. As of now your data structure isn't consistent at all and that will make any function that touch this data way more complicated and error prone. You can model this data as a map:

```
(def data  {:a "whatever"
            :b nil
            :c "foo"
            :e nil
            :f "boo"
            :g nil
            :h nil
            :i 62281})
```

And then to get the desired result:

```
(->> (vals data)
     (filter (comp not nil?))
     (into []))
```

But for some strange reason you still want to parse the data structure you provided then:

```
(defn get-values [data]
  (->> (map #(if (map? %) (into [] %) %)  data)
       flatten
       (filter #(or (string? %) (number? %)))
       (into [])))
```

Comment: "Fix the data" isn't really all that helpful being as you don't know the context, but the second part does the job, and I'll dig through it myself to see exactly what you did there. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, but the data you provided didn't necessitate its structure. No key was repeated, no inner mapping had more than one key, and every vector was 2 elements beginning with a keyword. Given those constraints, it's awkward to represent the data this way. Instead of trying to parse the data structure you provided, I would be spending my time trying to understand why I have that data structure in the first place.

Comment: I'm well aware of what the data structure looked like and how it could be different/better, but my question was how one would parse a complex list like that regardless of how or why I have that list. What you're saying is a akin to saying "Don't drive in to one." when a guy asks how he could get a car out of a ditch. It's obvious, but not particularly helpful or educational.